# Как узнать номер последней строки в текстовом файле?

Tags: файлы, php

Скажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте `wc -l`

Comment: Это как можно скрипт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = file('file.txt');
echo count($array);
/*-------------------------------------------*/

$str = file_get_contents('file.txt');
echo substr_count($str "\n");

/*-------------------------------------------*/

$h = fopen('r','file.txt');
$count = 0;
while (!feof($h)) {
    fgets($h);
    $count++;
}
echo $count;

/*-------------------------------------------*/

trim(exec("wc -l file.txt"));
```